# awk command to find and replace values

Tags: linux, awk

I need a help w.r.t. following code which I have difficulty understanding. Really appreciate if someone could take out a little time out of their schedule to explain this.

What it basically does is locate a row in based on col1 in file2 based on value in col1 of file1 and replace 7 column values in file2, the position of these columns are provided as input via -v flag.

```
awk --lint '-F|' -v col1pos=5 -v col2pos=29 -v col3pos=114 -v col4pos=115 -v col5pos= -v col6pos=26 -v col7pos= -v col8pos= 'BEGIN{OFS = FS; a[var 2] = col1pos; a[var 3] = col2pos; a[var 4] = col3pos; a[var 5] = col4pos; a[var 6] = col5pos; a[var 7] = col6pos; a[var 8] = col7pos; a[var 9] = col8pos} NR == FNR {a[$1] = $2; for (i
= 3; i <= 9; ++i) a[$1 FS i] = $i; next} $col1pos in a {for (i = 9; i >= 3; --i) if (length(a[var i]) > 0) $(a[var i]) = a[$col1pos FS i]; $col1pos = a[$col1pos]}1' file1 file2
```

Comment: If using GNU awk, add `-omyscript.awk` to the options to get a pretty-printed version in that file. Might be easier to understand that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no samples are provided so it is bit difficult to understand your complete problem; if we talk in terms of code then I have tried my best to explain it as below. Please go through it and let me know in case of any queries.

***Explanation of code:***

```
awk --lint '-F|' -v col1pos=5 -v col2pos=29 -v col3pos=114 -v col4pos=115 -v col5pos= -v col6pos=26 -v col7pos= -v col8pos= '                   ##Starting awk program from here and mentioning all variables with values as per OP need.
BEGIN{                                   ##Starting BEGIN section of awk program which will be executed before Input_file reading.
  OFS = FS                               ##Setting OFS to FS (1st point)
  a[var 2] = col1pos                     ##Creating an array named a whose index is var 2(2nd point) and setting its value to variable col1pos. Similarly creating other elements of array in next statements.
  a[var 3] = col2pos
  a[var 4] = col3pos
  a[var 5] = col4pos
  a[var 6] = col5pos
  a[var 7] = col6pos
  a[var 8] = col7pos
  a[var 9] = col8pos
}                                        ##Closing BLOCK for BEGIN section here.
NR == FNR{                               ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first Input_file named file1 is being read.
  a[$1]=$2                               ##Creating an array named a whose index is $1 and value is $2 of current line.
  for(i=3;i<=9;i++){                     ##Starting a for loop which starts from i=3 to till value of 9 here.
    a[$1 FS i]=$i                        ##Creating an array named a whose index is $1 FS and i and value is $i(i variable value column)
  }
    next                                 ##next will make sure no further statements are getting executed from here.
}                                        ##Closing BLOCK for FNR==NR condition here.
($col1pos in a){                         ##Checking condition if field number whose value is variable col1pos is present in array a, if yes then go further.
  for(i = 9; i >= 3; --i){               ##Starting a for loop from i=9 to till value of 3.
    if(length(a[var i]) > 0){            ##Checking condition if length of array a with index var i value is greater than 0 then do following.
      $(a[var i]) = a[$col1pos FS i]     ##Assigning field value(which will be decided on value of variable a[var i]) and setting it to value of array a with index $col1pos FS i.
    }                                    ##Closing if condition BLOCK here.
    $col1pos = a[$col1pos]               ##Setting value of field(which will be decided as per variable value col1pos) and setting it to array a value whose value is, value of field(col1pos).
  }                                      ##Closing BLOCK for; for loop here.
}                                        ##Closing BLOCK for condition here.
1                                        ##Mentioning 1 will print edited/non-edited lines.
' file1 file2                            ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

***NOTE:*** There are 2  points I mentioned for improvement of code, mentioning their meaning here.

- 1st point: NO need to set `OFS=FS` since by default both have same value as space.
- 2nd point: Be careful while setting index of an array, if its a string then use `a["string"]` or in case of using variable try `a[variable]`

Comment: Awesome, I have been trying to decipher this since last 3 days. Thanks a lot for crisp and precise explanation. It really helped. Thanks again.

Comment: Is there any specific reason of using `--lint` option here?

Comment: @anubhava, hello sir, I think I took OP's code and tried to fix it cheers :)